# Display google map with boundary lines for each address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google-earth, parcel, zillow

I am working on Google MAP API integration and I have tried to display the map with boundary lines for each address, such as Zillow.com.

Eg: http://www.zillow.com/homes/for_sale/priced_sort/25.945776,-80.147139,25.9432,-80.152374_rect/17_zm/

Zillow gives a neighborhood api/db file with boundaries and I'm not able to make sense of it exactly. How to get map view like their view with the DB data?

I have addresses with latitude/longitude. Using these addresses and latitude/longitude can I draw the boundary line for each address? If the address specifies a building then it needs to display it with its boundary line. Is there any API from google MAP or third party?

Please give me suggestion on this - I went through google search results and related articles on this and couldn't get any result.

Comment: Zillow is using Bing Maps not Google Maps the parcel data you want is in JSON (Polygon) format see http://map.zillowstatic.com/map/data/mapData2?row=111497&col=72706&zoom=17&communities=true&fmt=json&ver=1&name=__boundaryManagerTile_111497_72706_17

Comment: @Mapperz How can I get the parcel data from zillow? and how to draw polygon using that data?

Comment: tax cad offices usually have parcel data, if they are willing to give it to you is another story